# Multihreading a with parallels and degrees on a "For" statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I recently learned this bit of code the other day...

```
    Directory.GetFiles(fileLoc).AsParallel.WithDegreeOfParallelism(3).ForAll(Sub(path) theWorker(path))
```

and it has drastically improved a few of my programs and it has me wondering if this could also be used on nested for statements?

```
        For x As Integer = 0 To 99
            For y As Integer = 0 To 99
                For z As Integer = 0 To 99
                   dowork(x, y, z)
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

would it be possible to do something like this?

```
For x As Integer = 0 To 99
        For y As Integer = 0 To 99
            Parallel.For(0,99,Sub(z) dowork(x,y,z).WithDegreeOfParallelism(3)
        Next
  Next
```

or would I have to do something like this to actually make it work?

```
    Dim thelist As New List(Of String)

    For x As Integer = 0 To 99
        thelist.Add(x)
    Next


    For x As Integer = 1 To 99
        For y As Integer = 0 To 99
            thelist.AsParallel.WithDegreeOfParallelism(3).ForAll(Sub(z) dowork(x,y,z))
        Next
    Next
```

As a side question, does the degrees of parallelism correspond to the number of cores dedicated to the task? If I had a 24 core server, could I essentially set the DOP to 12 and use half the CPU power to run these processes?

If someone could teach/explain this to me it would be greatly appreciated : )

Thanks -Z

Comment: You have Parallel.For and Parallel.ForEach. The corresponding MSDN articles include clear sample codes showing how to implement both of them. You might use Parallel.For in all the loops you are showing. In any case, note that loops are extremely quick and relying on the parallel versions is only worthy under very specific conditions (e.g., lots of iterations). Also note that parallel-processing and multi-threading are different things (deleted this tag).

Comment: I dont think that the MSDN article that you are refering to is very clear when it comes to dealing with Parallel.For for the above situation - could you show me how to use it in the above example? ... Also, am I correct in assuming that the parallel processing corresponds to the number of cores in a system?

Comment: The title is descriptive ("Write a Simple Parallel.For Loop"): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 Note that the syntax is a bit weird but as far as the sample case is very simple you should be able to easily adapt it to your situation. You have basically to redefine each loop completely as described in the sample.

Comment: Note that I haven't used these parallel functionalities too much (don't even recommend them; in fact, I had some not-too-good past experiences); and only the loops with their default configuration. In fact, I haven't ever heard about this WithDegreeOfParallelism property but, as said for the loops: MSDN is usually a good source of information (do a quick research). In any case, you should firstly worry about having ready the parallel loops, rather than about tuning features.